# createBottomTabNavigator Hide one of the tabs

Tags: react-native

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Overview: {
      screen: OverviewStack,
    },
    Activities: {
      screen: ActivityStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Activity',
      },
    },
    Workout: {
      screen: WorkoutStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Workout',
      },
    },
....
.....
```

I would like to have one of the tab hidden. I can comment the code and it will disapear but I still want it to be working on the background but without any tab showing.
is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I made it using React Navigation 5 API ! One of the tabs is rendered AND hidden as you asked for.

1 - Use the example of the ***tabBar*** parameter available at :
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbar

2 - Assuming you want process and hide the 3rd tab (i.e. the tab at index 2), make the following modification to the example :

```
@@ -47,7 +47,8 @@ function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
         testID={options.tabBarTestID}
         onPress={onPress}
         onLongPress={onLongPress}
-            style={{ flex: 1 }}
+            style={{ flex: 1, display: index === 2 ? "none" : "flex" }}
       >
         <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? '#673ab7' : '#222' }}>
           {label}
```

> **IMPORTANT** : Using React Navigation **4** API, it must work almost the same way using the
> ***tabBarComponent*** property instead of the ***tabBar*** property.

Unfortunately, v4 is no longer available on npmjs.com, so I cannot help you any further.